# Active Directory: Retrieving data from domain component

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to obtain all the users and the groups (that this users belong to), from an active directory. I have this following powershell script, which gives me just the users from an specific OU, and also apparently there are groups that did not appear in the result, maybe because they got limited to the "ITE" OU:

```
$UsersPerGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=ITE,OU=HQ,DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```

I would like to change it so i get all the data from the "idb" level, not just "ITE"

What I tried is the following script:

```
#Get Membership of Users
$UsersPerGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```

and i got these a list of many errors errors:

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=RandSATestStubbing,CN=Users,DC=iadb,DC=org' under: 'DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org'.
At line:4 char:25
+ Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -j ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=RandSATestSt...,DC=iadb,DC=org:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup



Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=Exchange Recipient Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=iadb,DC=org' under: 'DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org'
At line:4 char:25
+ Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -j ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Exchange Rec...,DC=iadb,DC=org:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup



Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=Exchange Organization Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=iadb,DC=org' under: 'DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=o
At line:4 char:25
+ Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -j ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Exchange Org...,DC=iadb,DC=org:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

... the list continues

I also tried this:

```
$UsersPerGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | % { Get-ADGroup -Identity $_ -Server ($_ -replace '^.*?DC=','DC=') } | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```

Greetings!

Comment: You only limit the user search to "idb" (which you can modify in searchbase if you need). If your are missing groups then they are most likely indirect memberships (member through another group. Memberof only shows direct memberships), it is set as primary group for the user (which is not listed in memberof and should 99% of the time be "domain users") or you are missing permission to the groups (unlikely)

Comment: How would i limit the user search to "idb"? i tried by deleting until "ou=hq," but I did not succeed.

Comment: The value is a distinguishedname (DN) which is a comma-separated path for the OU/container starting from the right. If you want to search at the IDB-level then you have to remove every part to the left of it which in this example would be "ou=users,ou=ite,ou=hq," (remember to remove the comma at the end)

Comment: @FrodeF. yes, I tried by removing "ou=users,ou=ite,ou=hq," and it returns me lots of errors, like if there was no matching. what did you mean with DN, I also have to change DC by DN?

Comment: The searchbase paramter expects a DN (distinguishedName)-value, which is a type of path (like UNC for fileshares \\server\share\folder). `-SearchBase "DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org"` should work. If you get errors, you should update the question with the attempted code and error

Comment: @FrodeF. Oh ok, I just updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176879/discussion-between-jplaudir8-and-frode-f).

Comment: Forgot to convert from DN/LDAP to FQDN-format for the `-Server` property in the comment, so I've replaced it with an answer

Answer (score 0):

Update the searchbase parameter to the DN (distinguishedName) for the level in your domain you want to start the search from.

The AD module doesn't chase referrals (cross-domain), so you have to specify the correct domain when piping "memberof" to `Get-ADGroup`. Try (untested):

```
#Get Membership of Users
$UsersPerGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | % { Get-ADGroup -Server ($_ -replace '^.*?DC=' -replace ',DC=', '.') | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```